# How to install BaseX on CentOS?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, xml, database

How do I install basex on `CentOS`?

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ sudo yum install basex
Last metadata expiration check: 0:16:02 ago on Mon 15 Jun 2020 05:19:44 PM PDT.
No match for argument: basex
Error: Unable to find a match: basex
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ yum repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:30 ago on Mon 15 Jun 2020 05:35:21 PM PDT.
repo id                                   repo name                                                                           status
AppStream                                 CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                4,901
BaseOS                                    CentOS-8 - Base                                                                     1,672
*epel                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                      5,804
*epel-modular                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                  0
extras                                    CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                      20
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core) 
Release:    8.1.1911
Codename:   Core
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

From what I gather:

https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=52546

I need to add a repo?

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/basex:/opensuse/CentOS_7/

I see that:

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/basex:/opensuse/CentOS_7/home:basex:opensuse.repo

shows:

```
[home_basex_opensuse]
name=BaseX openSUSE Build (CentOS_7)
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/basex:/opensuse/CentOS_7/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/basex:/opensuse/CentOS_7/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
```

which is for `CentOS` 7.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t appear that the person maintaining those repos have built it for CentOS 8. Feel free to contact the repo maintainer, or rebuild the RPM yourself from [the source RPM](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/basex:/opensuse/CentOS_7/src/).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-configure-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8-run-rational-clearcase

```
sudo yum -y group install base-x
```

It looks like `basex` and `base-x` are slightly different.